# Trying to change a path inside an .m3u Playlist

Tags: windows, powershell-7.0

I have a lot of Playlist files (.m3u) created on one system that I need to move to another system. The files reference the original location which I need to change to a new location on a different system.  I have been using PowerShell7 and a command line I have found in this question:
Change files' encoding recursively on Windows?

.m3u format

#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:690,Aaron Copland, Detroit Symphony Orchestra, Leonard Slatkin - Billy the Kid: VIIa. Billy's Death
E:\My Music\Aaron_Copland,_Detroit_Symphony_Orchestra,*Leonard_Slatkin\Copland_Grohg*&_Billy_the_Kid\15-Billy_the_Kid_VIIa._Billy's_Death.flac
#EXTINF:830,Aaron Copland, Detroit Symphony Orchestra, Leonard Slatkin - Billy the Kid: VIIb. Billy's Funeral. Mourning Mexicans
E:\My Music\Aaron_Copland,_Detroit_Symphony_Orchestra,*Leonard_Slatkin\Copland_Grohg*&_Billy_the_Kid\16-Billy_the_Kid_VIIb._Billy's_Funeral._Mourning_Mexicans.flac

Any and all help appreciated.
Don

Get-ChildItem path E:\My_MM_Playlists -File | foreach ($F){ (gc $F) -replace 'E:\My Music','D:\MusicBackup\My Music' | sc $F }

This fails with a Path Does not Exist error, but I can verify in File Manager that it does. I am also not sure if this will change every instance of the path in each file.

I have also used this syntax:
Get-ChildItem E:\My_MM_Playlists -File | ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content - $*.FullName -Raw) -replace 'E:\My Music', 'D:\MusicBackup\My Music' |
Set-Content $*.FullName
}

With similar results.

I expected each file to be opened and the internal path changed to the new setting.